# Is $x-y \ne 0$ a transitive relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, function-and-relation-composition

I know that for a relation R is transitive if, for all elements ***aRb*** and ***bRc*** implies ***aRc***.

I came across this question, **" Is x-y  ≠ 0 transitive?"**

I think it is transitive since

> x - y  ≠ 0
>
> y - z  ≠ 0
>
> So we get x - z  ≠ 0.

But the answer says that it is not transitive, since it wouldn't be valid for the case where x = z.

Shouldn't a,b and c be distinct?

I am confused as the answer given is essentially building the argument saying that(with the use of only two elements)

> x - y  ≠ 0
>
> y - x  ≠ 0
>
> x - x  ≠ 0
>
> Therefore it is not transitive.

Would highly appreciate if you could make it clear if **x-y ≠ 0** is transitive or not and why it is so.

Comment: Does $!=$ means $\neq$ ?

Comment: Yes....Sorry I don't know how to get the inequality sign that way

Comment: "Shouldn't $a,b,c$ be distinct?" No, there's no such restriction. For **all** elements $aRb$ and $bRc$ implies $aRc$.

Comment: @AfiJaabb $0 \neq 1$ and $1 \neq 0$, but you have not $0 \neq 0$.

Comment: In the definition, replace $a$ with $x$, $b$ with $y$ and $c$ with $x$. If there exist $x$ and $y$ with $x-y\ne0$, then also $y-x\ne0$ but abviously $x-x=0$, meaning that $x-x\ne0$ is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

*I am confused as the answer given is essentially building the argument saying that

(with the use of only two elements).*

The arguments is not using just 2 elements, it's using 3 elements.
It's just that the 3rd one ($x$) happens to be the same as the first ($x$).
In the definition for transitivity, no one says the elements taking part should be different.

So **the relation is not transitive**.

Take any two elements $x,y$ such that $x \ne y$. Now take a third element $z = x$. Test these three elements (against the definition), and you will see that the transitivity does not hold true for these 3 elements.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple: let $x \neq y$ in $X$ (the set on which $R$ is defined, which we need to have two points or more, or else $R = \{((x,y) \mid x \neq y\} = \emptyset$ and that is trivially a transitive relation.)

Note that $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,x) \in R$ but $(x,x) \notin R$, thereby showing $R$ is not transitive. One such example suffices to show that.